# select only one card reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating 3 cards and I need you to be able to select one of them and it has a div inside when I select it and change the css, the example that I have the selected card is the second one and I would like the same to happen with the others but that only one can be selected at the same time

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="card"></div>
      <div className="card cardSelect">
        <div className="select">select</div>
      </div>
      <div className="card"></div>
    </div>
  );
}


.card {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background: red;
  margin: 1rem;
}
.cardSelect {
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: Please add logic to your component and show an issue with your code. SO is not supposed to be a job posting forum :D

Comment: @JulianKleine I have not added logic since I do not know how to do it, I have added a simple code since I can not put my work code so there are only 3 simple cards without something complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using an orchestrator, or a parent component.
[I have created you a simpler example at code sandbox](http://%5Bhttps://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-ride-pllde?file=/src/App.js%5D)

The active card needs to be controlled from a higher instance. In this case it is the App component it self. But you can create a Cards and Card component to encapsulate it. e.g.

```
<Cards>
   <Card />
   <Card />
   <Card />
</Cards>
```

Here is the code of the example in the code sandbox:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const cardStyle = {
  width: "5rem",
  height: "5rem",
  background: "red",
  margin: "1rem"
};

const cardSelect = {
  boxShadow: "2px 4px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)"
};

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{ ...cardStyle, ...(selected === 0 && cardSelect) }}
        onClick={() => setSelected(0)}
      >
        {selected === 0 && <div className="select">select</div>}
      </div>

      <div
        style={{ ...cardStyle, ...(selected === 1 && cardSelect) }}
        onClick={() => setSelected(1)}
      >
        {selected === 1 && <div className="select">select</div>}
      </div>

      <div
        style={{ ...cardStyle, ...(selected === 2 && cardSelect) }}
        onClick={() => setSelected(2)}
      >
        {selected === 2 && <div className="select">select</div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to

1. Add a state in the app level selection somewhere, eg. `const [selection, setSelection] = useState('card-0')
2. Create a component for cards, e.g.
3. Render that component three times <CardComponent isSelected={selection === 'card-2'} />`
4. Inside Cardcomponent, add that class only if it is selected. `className={"card " + prop.isSelected ? "cardSelect" : ""}`

Comment: Intentionally left you something to learn & research